# Bar chart of the number of occurrences in a JSON

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I've got a JSON of politicians, a list containing their names and party.

Very simply, what I want to do is having a bar chart, the size of the bars depending of the number of politicians from a different party.

Keys look like that:

```
{
    "party": "National Liberal Party – True Liberalism",
    "region": "london",
    "name": "Bernard Dube",
    "twitter": ""
  },
  {
    "party": "Alliance Party of Northern Ireland",
    "region": "northern-ireland",
    "name": "Anna Lo",
    "twitter": "Anna4Europe"
  },
```

Unfortunately, it is not as simple as:

```
{
"National Liberal Party": "330", 
"Alliance Party of Northern Ireland": "200"
}
```

How can I do that with d3? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

build the data u want:

```
var d = {};
records.forEach(function(i)  {
  if(d[i.party] == null) {
    d[i.party] = 0;
  }
  d[i.parts] += 1;
});
```

Comment: Thank you! It returns the object I want. Then, if I want to draw the graph, I guess that part is wrong: ```  d3.selectAll("div.line")
    .append("div")
    .attr("class","bar")
    .style("width", function(d){return d + "px"})```

Comment: try to build an example on jsbin.com!
at least I think u miss `enter` and `exit`. Also its not quite logical to select div.line but then create div.bar.

Comment: Yes, it will be easier. [Here you go](http://jsbin.com/nidukiko/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: I think u havent understand the basic concept of d3. check out this working example: http://jsbin.com/nidukiko/4/edit

Comment: I can still be confused by the simplest stuff. Thanks for your help - [final JSFiddle](http://jsbin.com/xodecuqu/2/).